# Opencart: Hide custom menu when specified Group cusomer logged

Tags: php, opencart

I have 3 customer groups in my OpenCart site as follows:

- Owner - id `1`
- Seller - id `2`
- Guest - id `3`

User can access my opencart website only after logging in - that's working fine. I have added a custom menu item into my site's header, e.g.

```
<a href="<?php echo $cusomtlink; ?>">Custome Menu</a>
```

My quetion is: **how do I hide this custom menu item for customer group id `2`**?

Comment: @shadyyx  i didn't tried anything yet.. because i don't know where i start... can you suggest any idea.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Your `catalog/controller/common/header.php` Header controller and add this line before the `$this->render();` line:

```
$this->data['customer_group_id'] = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
```

Then go to Your header template file, where a custom menu item is added, and change it to this:

```
<?php if($customer_group_id != 2) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $cusomtlink; ?>">Custom Menu</a>
<?php } ?>
```

This should do it.

**EDIT:** Should You need to hide the menu item for more groups, You could do:

```
<?php if(!in_array($customer_group_id, array(2, 3, 7, 8))) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $cusomtlink; ?>">Custom Menu</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @shaddyx your answer is correct, thanks... but one question, how to hide this menu even group id 3 customer logged also.??